# Cache error on file upload with media, multiform, and plupload

Tags: 7, media, files

Checkout the log entries for a site I am working on, I found multiple pairs of the following notice/error:

> Error: Form build-id mismatch detected while attempting to store a
>   form in the cache. Notice: Undefined index: #build_id in
>   form_set_cache() (line 564 of /dir/includes/form.inc).

I am using media-2.x with plupload and multiform. The above messages are always logged for all files uploaded through plupload at file/add. Any ideas what is going on here and how to fix it? There will be a lot of file uploads on this site, and I really don't want the database filling up with these log entries.

I am getting these messages with Pantheon and with my local environment, so going to assume it is not a server configuration issue, Core and all modules are up to date. Php is 5.4.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in a third-party module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in multiform that was introduced by recent changes to Drupal Core. The bug has been reported in the module's issue queue and a patch has been provided: https://drupal.org/node/2247527

The patch fixed the issue for me, and hopefully will be included in the next release of the module.

Comment: Is this for the Multiform module itself? Also I should note, that despite the error messages, I am still able to upload files without issue. It's just a matter of the database log ballooning with error messages.

Comment: Yep, the patch is for the Multiform module. I had the same issue as you -- I was seeing the same notices in my error log, but everything was still functioning. I searched around for a cause and actually came upon your question first. I kept looking and  came upon the issue with the patch. Applying the patch solved the issue for me, so I came back here to share what I found.

Comment: Awesome, just had a chance to test out the patch. Works as described. Thanks so much!